# Error trying to dismiss Ionic Loader

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an Ionic3 application which posts data to an API based on an action, whilst waiting for the action to complete I show a loader using Ionic's LoadingController.

```
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

I declare the loader by:

```
this.loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
   content: "Please wait..."
});
```

I then use the loader:

```
doSomething(item) {

    this.loader.present().then(()=>{

      this.item.begin(item).then((result) => {

        this.data = result;
        this.loader.dismiss();

      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.loader.dismiss();
      });

    });

  }
```

I get the error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): inserted view was already
>   destroyed

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Environment:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.10.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.10.3

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
    Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.1

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2
    Node       : v7.7.1
    npm        : 4.1.2
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [loading controller doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/loading/LoadingController/)

> Note that after the component is dismissed, it will not be usable anymore and another one must be created. This can be avoided by wrapping the creation and presentation of the component in a reusable function as shown in the usage section below.

So your error it's because you have the create and present split.

```
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) { }

presentLoadingDefault() {
  const loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Please wait...'
  });

  loading.present();

  setTimeout(() => {
    loading.dismiss();
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that I'll give it a go, looks like it should work.. My only comment is will this work even after an Ajax call? so when the call is finished I can call loading.dismiss() without having to wait for the default 5000?

Comment: the 5000 it just for example, once your call is done you should subscribe to the observable returned or promise(if you are using promise) and call the dismiss on it.

Comment: Apologies, I don't understand how the 5000 is for example, I use a promise in my http call. 

this.presentLoadingDefault();

    this.getDebt().then((res) => {
      this.data = res;
      this.customers = this.data.data;
      this.loading.dismiss();
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

Comment: I kinda want to avoid creating const loading in every function on my controller

Comment: the 5000 is just a timer once that time has passed the dismiss will be call. In your case after the present inside presentLoadingDefault() put your http request and place the dismiss inside the 'then' once you have done all your logic

Comment: I use let instead of const, but the point is that you have to create it again after being dismissed as noted on the official doc.

Comment: Ahh so creating and dismissing every time is the only option, thanks for your help